# How to map the value in Mapper

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I have a file with data like

```
City,Quarter,Classification,Index
Bordeux,Q1,R,3 
Krakow,Q1,U,2 
Halifax,Q1,U,4
```

I need to find out the highest Index in each Classification and write them to two separate files.  The output should be

```
Bordeux,Q1,R,3
Halifax,Q1,U,4
```

How to load the data in `Mapper` as it requires a key/value pair.  In mapper it seems programmer should not do any modification to data.  So, how to load it in `Context` object.

I think the data type of key or value is not changed in `Reducer`. If so, I'm going to infuse my logic to find the top records, then how to organize into a context object there.

I don't have clue on how to proceed.

Necessary pointers will help me to proceed further.

Comment: I suggest you to first write a simple wordcount program and understand how it works. It's explained very well in the hadoop docs.

Comment: Hi, thanks for guidance.  I've done the word count and custom word count. the input being key/value pair, didn't feel anything tough.  but this comma delimited value input data is, i don't know how to/where to start. so far changed the logic with mapper thrice and reducer twice, still i couldn't get a grasp of the solution.  Mapper Solution 1. made only the name as key and rest as value and got blocked at Reducer on processing reading the value data. As a plain java or python program I'm able to solve it, but through hadoop, i'm struck

Comment: @luckyluke you parse each of the lines (since mapper receives each cycle one line only) and set the Classification as a map output key and Index as a map output value. In reducer, you will already have grouped values for each of the Classifications, so you simple iterate through the list and find the largest number.. it is very simple.

Comment: @luckyluke Each line that is passed to mapper is in the form of <key, value> where `value` contains each line of the file. In your mapper, you need to perform whatever operations you want to this `value` and again output a key-value pair using `context.write` so that it can be further passed to the reducer. Edit with whatever code you have written so far and we will be able to help you better.

Answer (score 0):

In your case when you read the file in Mapper the input key is the ObjectId of the line and value is the line itself. So in other words, in each line of the file will be received in Mapper as value field. Now, the output (key,value) of Mapper should be (Classification, Index). 
The output of Mapper will become input (key,value) of reducer. So reducer will receive (Classification,Iterable) as input. So for each classification, you can iterate over Index List to get the Max and output of the reducer will be (Classification,Max)

In this case, output key and value type will be same in for Mapper and Reducer.

However, regarding writing it to separate lines: Separate files will be generated only if every key is routed to different reducer instance. So in your case, the total number of reducers should be equal to the total number of unique classifications(Not in good terms of resource utilization though). So, you have to write a custom partitioner to make it happen